VBA Coding for sending a form in email in excel
I have created an overtime form in excel.  What I'm trying to do is to email the overtime form to a supervisor for approval then the supervisor emails/forwards the approval to the secretary that inputs the time in. I get an error/debug at the end .Send highlights in yellow.
Any help word be greatly appreciated
Sub Rectangle1_Click()

    Dim selectedemployee As String
    
    selectedemployee = Range("B16")
    
    Dim recipientemail As String
    
    recipientemail = Lookupvalue = Range("b16")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set objoutlook = CreateObject("outlook.application")
    
    Dim objemail As Object
    
    Set objemail = objoutlook.Createitem(0)
    
    With objemail
        .To = recipientemail
        .Subject = "overtime slip for " & selectedemployee
        .Body = "please review the attachedovertime slip."
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Display
        .Send
    End With
    
    Set objemail = Nothing
    Set objoutlook = Nothing
        
End Sub

I have googled and tried different VBA, but still nothing. I have gotten the email to send once, but when it did it showed false as the name in the To: spot.

"in yellow"? what yellow?

recipientemail = Lookupvalue = Range("b16") what do you intend this line to do?

@SolarMike the yellow he's referring to is when there's an error and it highlights where the error occurred.

Do you have a lookup table which maps selectedemployee to their manager's email address?  Remember we have no idea what your worksheet looks like...

The following line returns either TRUE or FALSE, not the the recepient email as intended.
recipientemail = Lookupvalue = Range("b16")

What you meant was probably something like that:
Sub Rectangle1_Click()

    Dim selectedemployee As String
    Dim recipientemail As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim objoutlook As Object
    Dim objemail As Object
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler ' Start error handling
    
    ' Check if the cell B16 has a value
    If IsEmpty(Range("B16").Value) Then
        MsgBox "The email address is missing in cell B16.", vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Assign the value from B16 (the email) to recipientemail
    selectedemployee = Range("B16").Value
    recipientemail = Range("B16").Value
    
    ' Check if email address is in a valid format
    If InStr(1, recipientemail, "@") = 0 Or InStr(1, recipientemail, ".") = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The email address in cell B16 is invalid.", vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Create Outlook email object
    Set objoutlook = CreateObject("outlook.application")
    Set objemail = objoutlook.CreateItem(0)
    
    ' Compose and send email
    With objemail
        .To = recipientemail
        .Subject = "Overtime slip for " & selectedemployee
        .Body = "Please review the attached overtime slip."
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Display ' Remove this line if you want to send the email without previewing it
        .Send ' Uncomment this line if you want the email to be sent automatically
    End With
    
    ' Clean up
    Set objemail = Nothing
    Set objoutlook = Nothing
    
    Exit Sub ' Ensures the error handler doesn't run if there was no error

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    ' Optional: Add logging to a file or sheet if needed
    Resume Next
End Sub


The recipientemail = Lookupvalue = Range("b16") is the column where the drop down list has the names of the people to choose from to send an email to.

"b16" is not a column, it is a cell.  And your code, as it is right now, does not put the value of "b16" in the variable recipientemail.  What is does, it compares the non-existing variable Lookupvalue to the value of the cell "b16" and likely returns FALSE. As it stands my corrected code sends an email with the addressed to the email address in cell "b16".
